# Loop while cleanup object (only android)

Tags: android, appcelerator, destroy, appcelerator-titanium

I'm facing a weird bug on android, I've a page view that has side view (SIDE) that loads an content view (FILTER), than this filter view loads another view (FORM) and this last one loads some views (TEXT)

```
[INFO] :   ADD :: TEXT
[INFO] :   ADD :: TEXT
[INFO] :   ADD :: FORM
[INFO] :   ADD :: FILTER
[INFO] :   ADD :: SIDE
```

When I close the active page view, this calls a cleanup function on the child views:

```
$.page.cleanup = function() {
    side.cleanup();
};

console.log('ADD :: SIDE');
$.side.cleanup = function() {
    console.log('DESTROY :: SIDE');
    filter.cleanup();
    //remove listeners, and null objects
};

console.log('ADD :: FILTER');
$.filter.cleanup = function() {
    console.log('DESTROY :: FILTER');
    form.cleanup();
    //remove listeners, and null objects
};

console.log('ADD :: FORM');
$.form.cleanup = function() {
    console.log('DESTROY :: FORM');
    for(var i in text) text[i].cleanup();
    //remove listeners, and null objects
};

console.log('ADD :: TEXT');
$.text.cleanup = function() {
    console.log('DESTROY :: TEXT');
    //remove listeners, and null objects
};
```

But when I run the cleanup function in android, it starts a loop, on iOS works fine:

iOS:

```
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: SIDE
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: FILTER
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: FORM
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: TEXT
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: TEXT
```

android:

```
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: SIDE
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: FILTER
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: FORM
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: TEXT
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: TEXT
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: FILTER
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: FORM
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: FILTER
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: FORM
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: FILTER
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: FORM
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: FILTER
[INFO] :   CLEANUP :: FORM
...
```

Any idea??

Comment: The code doesn't show the hierarchy of views/cleanup you explain in your question, you are sure that form does not clean up anything linked to the filter?

Comment: The 'form' has multiple field types, if the types are 'time', 'date' or 'options', it creates another 'side', but in this exemple I'm using only the 'text' field, so when I destroy the 'form' the only inner elements to destroy are those 'text' fields, and the 'form' is only destroyed by the 'filter' view, the next 3 hours I'll be running some more tests, disabling the child views one by one to find the problem

Comment: By mistake I was cleaning up the buttons this way:
`for(var i in $.buttons) $.buttons[i].cleanup();`
instead of:
`for(var i in $.buttons.children) $.buttons.children[i].cleanup();`
don't know why but this creates a loop on filter view cleanup event, solved, thanks for the answer

Comment: Could you add the above as an answer to your question so you can accept it as the right answer which will close the question?

Comment: Ok, done, but I can't mark as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

By mistake I was cleaning up the buttons this way:

```
for(var i in $.buttons) $.buttons[i].cleanup();
```

Instead of:

```
for(var i in $.buttons.children) $.buttons.children[i].cleanup();
```

Don't know why but this creates a loop on filter view cleanup event, solved, thanks for the answer